# Exercise about signature of a scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $V:= M(n,\mathbb{R})$ be the vectorial space of square real matrix of order $n$. We define the scalar product $f:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(A,B):=tr(AB)$. We have to prove that the signature of $f$ is $(\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\frac{n(n-1)}{2},0)$. It is simple in the case $n=2,3$. In general, I have tried to build the associated matrix by using the canonical base, but it is difficult for me. There is another approach to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, working over $\mathbb R$ there is a very nice approach via symmetry.

observe that
$A = \frac{1}{2}\big(A+A^T\big) + \frac{1}{2}\big(A-A^T\big)$
and in particular we can split this vector space into the subspaces of symmetric matrices (H) and skew symmetric matrices (S)

i.) for $\mathbf H, \mathbf H' \in H$
$\dim H = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
$f\big(\mathbf H,\mathbf H'\big) = tr\big(\mathbf H \mathbf H'\big)=tr\big(\mathbf H^T\mathbf H'\big)$
which is the standard Frobenius inner product and is thus a positive definite form

ii.) for $\mathbf S,\mathbf S' \in S$
$\dim S = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$
$f\big(\mathbf S,\mathbf S'\big) = tr\big(\mathbf S \mathbf S'\big)= -tr\big(\mathbf S^T\mathbf S'\big)$
which is the negative of the standard Frobenius inner product and hence a negative definite form

iii.)  These are orthogonal subspaces with respect to symmetric bilinear form $f$ because for $\mathbf S \in S$ and $\mathbf H\in H$
$f\big(\mathbf S,\mathbf H\big) = tr\big(\mathbf S \mathbf H\big)= tr\big((\mathbf S\mathbf H)^T\big)= tr\big(\mathbf H^T \mathbf S^T\big)= tr\big(\mathbf S^T \mathbf H^T\big)= -tr\big(\mathbf S \mathbf H\big)$
$\longrightarrow f\big(\mathbf S,\mathbf H\big)= 0$

putting this all together, you have signature $\big(\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\frac{n(n-1)}{2},0\big)$

Comment: Thank you very much.